# need help finding error on my python code

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am Writing a program to prompt for a score between 0.0 and 1.0. If the score is out of range print an error. If the score is between 0.0 and 1.0, print a grade using the following table:Score Grade >= 0.9 A>= 0.8 B>= 0.7 C>= 0.6 D< 0.6 F.

To give an example of what it should do at the end it is:

Enter score: 0.95, A 
Enter score: perfect, Invalid input 
Enter score: 10.0, Invalid input
Enter score: 0.75, C 
Enter score: 0.5,  F

This is the code I have now:

```
score = input("Enter Score: ")


try:
    score= float(score)
    if(score >= 0.0 and score <= 1.0):
        if (score>= 0.9):
            print("A")
        elif (score>= 0.8):
            print("B")
        elif(score>= 0.7):
            print("C")
        elif (score>= 0.6):
            print("D")
        elif (score < 0.6):
            print("F")
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

I cant seem to get it up and running. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where's the `except` to go with your `try`?

Comment: Is an Exception being thrown? Or does it not work as you expected it to work?

Comment: I get *SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing*. You have to add an `except` to complete your *try/except* block.

Comment: You presented an assignment and a code. You didn't ask anything or say what's wrong with this code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Green-Avocado has a great answer. I would add a while loop to retry until the input is valid;

```
# loop until complete
while True:
    score = input("Enter Score: ")

    # let's try this 
    try:
        score = float(score)
        if score >= 0.0 and score <= 1.0:
            if score >= 0.9:
                print("A")
            elif score >= 0.8:
                print("B")
            elif score >= 0.7:
                print("C")
            elif score >= 0.6:
                print("D")
            elif score < 0.6:
                print("F")

            # exit the loop on completion
            break

        # else raise an exception
        raise

    # if problem with float(score) or exception raised
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `try` statement probably wants to do two things: verify that the user input can be converted to a `float`, and that the resulting float is in the range 0-100. Nothing else should be in the `try` statement.

If the value is not a float or out of range, you can let the loop continue to get another input. Otherwise, you can proceed with a single `if` statement to map the score to a letter grade.

```
while True:
    score = input("Enter score: ")

    try:
        score = float(score)  # Could raise ValueError
        if not (0 <= score <= 1.0):
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid input")
    else:
        break

if (score>= 0.9):
    print("A")
elif (score>= 0.8):
    print("B")
elif(score>= 0.7):
    print("C")
elif (score>= 0.6):
    print("D")
else:  # Only option left for an in-range value.
    print("F")
```

Strictly speaking, the range check could be moved out of the `try` statement as well:

```
while True:
    try:
        score = float(score)
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid input")
        continue

    if 0 <= score <= 1.0:
        break

    print("invalid input")
```

I converted the failed range check to a `ValueError` mainly to have one error message and one place where we use `break`, rather than an explicit `continue`. There are several ways to structure it, but the common feature is that you verify that `score` has a value suitable for the following grade map first.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `except` block after your `try` block to handle errors.
Instead of printing the error in the last `elif`, this can be used to handle all errors.
You can manually raise the error using `raise`.

```
score = input("Enter Score: ")

try:
    score = float(score)
    if score >= 0.0 and score <= 1.0:
        if score >= 0.9:
            print("A")
        elif score >= 0.8:
            print("B")
        elif score >= 0.7:
            print("C")
        elif score >= 0.6:
            print("D")
        else:
            print("F")
    else:
        raise
except:
    print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: The brackets don't hurt, though. The `if` statement just needs an expression, and expressions can be bracketed.

Comment: Ah, for some reason I never realised that, though looking back it seems obvious brackets would be allowed. Thanks for pointing that out @chepner.